# Firing change event on model change

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to trigger the 'change' javascript event on those all SELECT elements where model value changes. The values of model are changed programatically through scope, so using ngChange is out of the play (reacts only on user-made value changes).

Any help please?

Code example: [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/8aQrclp9wTNMAIAZx5Fd?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'oldname';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <select ng-model="name" class="myInput" onChange="alert('changed');" >
        <option value="oldname">oldname</option>
        <option value="newname">newname</option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="name='newname'">Change by Anguar</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Selecting select options shows alert. When I click the button, value (model) does get changed but alert is not shown because mode change doesn't trigger 'change' event.

Comment: please share your code to debug easily

Comment: @NagaSaiA added to question.

Comment: Please include all code necessary to answer the question, in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan all code necesarry is the question itself. I want after clicking the button the alert to fire. Used is library angularJs.

Comment: Fine, I'll do it for you...

Answer (score 1):

you can use $scope.$watch to watch for changes in the model and trigger change event

```
$scope.$watch('name', function(){
    //slct is the id for the select
    $('#slct').trigger('change');
  })
```

see [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zeoa6SKwkDhaMAN7MBMP?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, thank you, that would work in most cases. But I need my code to be general. Ie I have many elements with many models atached to them and I cannot write single watch statement for all of them.
If it could be done for something like:
    `$rootScope.$watch($('select').val(),, function(){
        $(this).trigger('change');
      });`

Comment: you can create a custom directive for a more generic solution see https://plnkr.co/edit/VYMBA9gac8TUFsqtB16x?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

onChange is a javascript event handler not tied to angular's digest loop. Try using ng-change instead.

Comment: As I stated, ngChange reacts only on user-made changes. It does't fire when model is changed programatically. More in angular doc.

Comment: What about $watch()?

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Would you provide an example? I need this code to be general - eg - not atached to any particular model. Instead for working on all of them.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It sounds like you want angular's ng-click to trigger an onChange event. this would be more appropriate for a directive.

Comment: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope. Here is a link to official document from angular. If that doesnt help out, I can provide an example for sure.